# Square-root equation with no solutions

Tags: radicals

There is an equation given:

$${\sqrt {3x-7}} + {\sqrt {2x-1}} = 0$$

Solving it algebraically:

$${(\sqrt {3x-7})^2} + {(\sqrt {2x-1})^2} = 0$$
$$ 3x-7 + 2x-1 = 0 $$
$$ 5x = 8 $$
$$ x = \frac{8}{5} $$

But doing it 
$${\sqrt {3x-7}} = {-\sqrt {2x-1}}$$
$${(\sqrt {3x-7})^2} = {(-\sqrt {2x-1})^2}$$
$$ 3x-7 = 2x-1 $$
$$ x = 6 $$

Both answer don't satisfy the given equation. I was told that you can't add two principle root's and expect to get a value zero, therefore there's no solution. But is that conclusion right?

Comment: Your first step takes you from $\alpha+\beta=0$ to $\alpha^2+\beta^2=0$ without justification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking about principle roots of reals, we have $\sqrt x\ge 0$ whenever it is defined (i.e., when $x\ge 0$). Hence both roots in the equation must be non-negative and so 
$$ \underbrace{\sqrt{3x-7}}_{\ge 0}+\underbrace{\sqrt{2x-1}}_{\ge 0}=0$$
is only possible when both summands on the left are $=0$. This, however, leads to $3x=7$ and $2x=1$, which cannot hold  at the same time.